# How to change Python version used by Bokeh?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.4, bokeh

When I launch my Python application I use the command:
bokeh serve application.py

This was working before on a Windows machine where only one Python version existed.

Now I am on a Linux machine where I have Python (version 2.7) and Python3 (version 3.4).

There is some native stuff on Linux using Python 2.7 so I cannot rename Python3 to Python.

Is there a way to tell Bokeh to use another Python version? If I do Bokeh info indeed says that the Python version is 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bokeh does not "use" a Python version. Bokeh is installed in to a Python environment, and when you run `bokeh serve` the Python version from the corresponding environment is used. That is how Python works in general, there is no way for Bokeh to behave differently.

The most likely explanation is that you have multiple Python environments, and the Python 2.7 environment is first on your system `PATH`. Make sure Bokeh is installed into the Python 3 environment (i.e. into its `site-packages`) and make sure that the `bin` directory for the Python 3 environment is first on your path (or run the Bokeh server by providing a full absolute path to the correct one).

Alternatively, you can run the Bokeh server with `-m`:

```
python -m bokeh serve app.py
```

In which case you can control exactly which Python executable is used, directly.

Comment: This is the answer. I solved it installing latest Python and using Python3.6 -m pip install bokeh and for launching my application as bigreddot mentioned: python -m bokeh serve app.py